# To calculate sum of qty based on date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below query I have 3 tables `GoodsReceivedNote`, `GoodsReceivedNoteDetail` and `TransferNote`. In the `GoodsReceivedNote` and `GoodsReceivedNoteDetail` I am receiving the product on a particular date on particular location. In `TransferNote` I am transferring the product from one location to another location. My objective is to sum the transfer qty of a product based on `grn` date of receiving date as `startdate` and next receiving date of that product in `grn` as `end date`. Here I will show the example.

```
[GoodsReceivedNote]    
GoodsReceivedNoteID | LocationID
--------------------+---------------
     1              |      1
     2              |      1

[GoodsReceivedNoteDetail]
GoodsReceivedNoteDetailID|GoodsReceivedNoteID|AcceptedQuantity|ProductID|CreatedON
-------------------------+-------------------+----------------+---------+-----------
    1                    | 1                 | 50             |  1      | 10-2-2015
    2                    | 2                 | 100            |  1      | 1-3-2015

[TransferNote]
Fromlocation |Tolocation|ProductID|TransferQuantity|CreatedOn  |
-------------+----------+---------+----------------+-----------+
 1              2             1       10           | 10-2-2015
 1              2             1       25           | 12-2-2015
 1              2             1       50           | 5-3-2015
```

My expected result:

```
GoodsReceivedNoteID|LocationID|AcceptedQuantity|ProductID|CreatedOn|Fromlocation |Tolocation|ProductID|TransferQuantity
-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---------+-----------------
1                  | 1        | 50             |   1     |10-2-2015|   1         |   2      |   1     |  35      
2                  | 2        | 100            | 1       |  1-3-15 |   1         |   2      |   1     |  50  


Select 
dbo.fn_MaterialTransferqty(GRN.LocationID,GRND.ProductID,GRND.CreatedON,GRND.CreatedON )
From GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID =GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransferNote TN ON Tn.ProductID=GRND.ProductID

Select GRN.LocationID,GRND.ProductID,GRND.ReceivedQuantity,
dbo.fn_MaterialTransferqty(GRN.LocationID,GRND.ProductID,GRND.CreatedOn,GRND.CreatedOn)
From GoodsReceivedNoteDetail GRND 
LEFT OUTER JOIN GoodsReceivedNote GRN ON GRN.GoodsReceivedNoteID =GRND.GoodsReceivedNoteID
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransferNote TN ON Tn.ProductID=GRND.ProductID
WHERE GRND.CreatedOn >=@i_StartDate AND   GRND.CreatedOn<=@i_EndDate
```

Comment: A simple `group by` and `sum` would appear to do the trick. But I'm not really sure what you've got inside that function.

Comment: @shawnt00  can u pls help me with query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return per product grn start and end dates, and sum the quantity from the transfers between these two dates:

```
select distinct grn.ProductID, grn.CreatedON StartDate, 
    (select min(CreatedON) from GoodsReceivedNoteDetail 
        where ProductID = grn.ProductID and CreatedON > grn.CreatedON
    ) EndDate,
    (select sum(TransferQuantity) from TransferNote
        where ProductID = grn.ProductID
        and CreatedOn >= grn.CreatedON 
        and CreatedOn <= 
            (select min(CreatedON) from GoodsReceivedNoteDetail 
                where ProductID = grn.ProductID and CreatedON > grn.CreatedON)
    ) Quantity
from GoodsReceivedNoteDetail grn
```

The EndDate is calculated as the next date for the product in grn.
The Quantity is the sum of the TransferQuantity in TransferNote between (including) the StartDate and the EndDate in grn.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess. Parts of this don't make sense to me.

```
select
    grn.GoodsReceivedNoteID, grn.LocationID,
    grnd.AcceptedQuantity, grnd.ProductID, grnd.CreatedOn,
    tn.Fromlocation, tn.Tolocation, tn.ProductID, /* why do you want this twice? */
    sum(TransferQuantity) as TransferQuantity
from
    GoodsReceivedNote as grn
    inner join GoodsReceivedNoteDetail as grnd
        on  grnd.GoodsReceivedNoteID = grn.GoodsReceivedNoteID
    inner join TransferNote as tn
        on  tn.Fromlocation = grn.LocationID
            and tn.ProductID = grn.ProductID /* is this correct? */
group by
    grn.GoodsReceivedNoteID, grn.LocationID,
    grnd.AcceptedQuantity, grnd.ProductID, grnd.CreatedOn,
    tn.Fromlocation, tn.Tolocation, tn.ProductID
```